# TCSH foreach Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Tags: linux, shell, unix, tcsh

So I have the basic script:

```
foreach x (*.nii)

        mri_convert -i $x -o $x:r.mgz -it nii -ot mgz
end
```

In essence, it should change the file type of all .nii files to .mgz. When I run this in tcsh, I receive:

```
./test1: 1: ./test1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I am really unsure why I am getting this error, as the correct syntax for the foreach is typically:

```
foreach x (1 2 3)

     echo $x
end
```

Am I mistaken?

Comment: It sounds like you're running the script with `sh` instead of tcsh. Make sure you have `#!/usr/bin/env tcsh` as the first line in the script. Using tcsh to issue the run command is not enough.

Comment: some shells require space chars to separate syntax elements. (I can't remember now if [t]csh requires that). Maybe `foreach x ( *.nil )` will help. But agree, you need something like `#!/bin/tcsh` as your first line. Good luck.

Comment: That was my issue, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following script should at least run without errors if you have tcsh OR csh shell on your machine.

```
#!/bin/tcsh

foreach x (*.nii)
  mri_convert -i $x -o $x:r.mgz -it nii -ot mgz
end
```